# Google Android LVL CheckLicense service timeout

Tags: android, android-lvl

I have an app that use Google license protection service. I have tested successfully this app(that currently is on Google Play since a couple of weeks) and the license checking.

Some days ago I have published another app with the same protection and another private

`static final byte[] SALT = new byte[] {....}`

And the license checking works fine also with this app.

Today I have updated a single layout of the first app published. 
I have tested the app and with my surprise fails the license checking with a timeout problem (and my Internet connection works fine)

```
10-25 01:04:16.689: I/LicenseChecker(2739): Binding to licensing service.
10-25 01:04:16.709: I/LicenseChecker(2739): Calling checkLicense on service for myapp.package.comu
10-25 01:04:16.709: I/LicenseChecker(2739): Start monitoring timeout.
10-25 01:04:26.719: I/LicenseChecker(2739): Check timed out.
10-25 01:04:28.579: I/LicenseChecker(2739): Binding to licensing service.
myapp.package.comu
10-25 01:04:28.609: I/LicenseChecker(2739): Start monitoring timeout.
10-25 01:04:38.619: I/LicenseChecker(2739): Check timed out.
```

I have already tried to change my license response from the console without success, license checking service doesn't responds anything to my app.

**In the second app with a different package and the same protection logic that I have published, LVL works without any problem.**

I cannot figure what could be the reason of this issue.

I have tried also to use the same *SALT* array without success.

Now I can only hope that buyers of the app haven't the same issue.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bug is on the Google Licensing Server or in Google Play App that for some strange reason randomly causes a data corruption in the settings and refuse the connection to the App. 
If you change the package name the server responds right.

Obviously change the package name is annoying and if app was already on the market is really problematic.

**A workaround is this:**

1) Uninstall the app

2) Clean all *Google Play Store* App data **not only the cache**, and *Google Play Service* data, in the phone setting.

3) Reopen Google Play and accept the end-user license agreement.

4) Reinstall the app.

I have tried to contact Google to Solve the problem.

Comment: To this day, I still have problems with this. I've found recently that I'll get about 10 or 15 solid license checks, then, all the sudden the license will come back as unlicensed, even though I've changed nothing. I often just re-install my apps, wait 30 seconds, and it works again.

Comment: @Silverstorm, I had tried this solution and many others, still facing same issue.