# Decompiled and modified apk is not installed

Tags: android, android-studio, decompiling

I decompile apk with apkstudio (apktool, apk-signer).
Then I add to the manifest android: debuggable = "true" in the  tag
After collecting and subscribing with apkstudio

I open the received apk using Android Studio install the application and profile it.
I am only interested in graphics in the profiler (CPU, RAM, Battery)

Everything worked more or less. But the last couple of days I can not put any such APK on Android above version 6.
On my Redmi 3S android 6.0.1 everything is put, but on Mi A 2Lite (android 9), Meizu M6 Note (android 7.1.2), Honor 9 Lite (android 8) is not installed.
More precisely, the application is installed, but when it starts to download additional resources it hangs.

Who knows what could have happened?

I tried both at home and at work.

Mi A 2 Lite Log

```
04/23 11:48:29: Launching zombie.survival.craft.z_mod2
$ adb push C:\Users\d.romanov\ApkProjects\zombie.survival.craft.z_mod2\zombie.survival.craft.z_mod.apk /data/local/tmp/zombie.survival.craft.z
$ adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/zombie.survival.craft.z"
Success
APK installed in 3 s 390 ms
$ adb shell am start -n "zombie.survival.craft.z/ru.kv3dunityext.permissions.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 6265 on device xiaomi-mi_a2_lite-24c2e93c0005
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/urvival.craft.: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
I/MultiDex: Installing application
    VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
D/FirebaseApp: Default FirebaseApp failed to initialize because no default options were found. This usually means that com.google.gms:google-services was not applied to your gradle project.
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 2df12b3, I07da2d9908
    Build Date                       : 10/04/18
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.25.03.01
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Reconstruct Branch               : 
I/Adreno: Build Config                     : S L 6.0.7 AArch32
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/DpmTcmClient: RegisterTcmMonitor from: com.android.okhttp.TcmIdleTimerMonitor
I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff110, ME: 0x005ff066
I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
    android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
W/urvival.craft.: Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;-><init>(Ljava/lang/Class;I)V (light greylist, reflection)
I/Unity: SystemInfo CPU = ARMv7 VFPv3 NEON, Cores = 8, Memory = 2826mb
    SystemInfo ARM big.LITTLE configuration: 8 big (mask: 0xff), 0 little (mask: 0x0)
I/Unity: ApplicationInfo zombie.survival.craft.z version 1.11.11 build 321aec15-e27b-4ce5-ba0f-5a1541345263
    Built from '2018.3/staging' branch, Version '2018.3.8f1 (fc0fe30d6d91)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'armeabi-v7a'
W/AnalyticsUserIDStore: initStore should have been called before calling setUserID
W/UserDataStore: initStore should have been called before calling setUserID
D/Unity:  GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_framebuffer_object GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_hdr GL_OES_texture_compression_astc GL_OES_texture_npot GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_OES_texture_3D GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_QCOM_alpha_test GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_EXT_sRGB GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_texture_format_sRGB_override GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_EXT_copy_image GL_EXT_geometry_shader GL_EXT_tessellation_shader GL_OES_texture_stencil8 GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks GL_OES_shader_image_atomic GL_OES_sample_variables GL_EXT_texture_border_clamp GL_EXT_EGL_i
    mage_external_wrap_modes GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture2 GL_OES_shader_multisample_interpolation GL_EXT_texture_cube_map_array GL_EXT_draw_buffers_indexed GL_EXT_gpu_shader5 GL_EXT_robustness GL_EXT_texture_buffer GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch GL_ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch_depth_stencil GL_OES_texture_storage_multisample_2d_array GL_OES_sample_shading GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_EXT_debug_label GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering GL_ANDROID_extension_pack_es31a GL_EXT_primitive_bounding_box GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query GL_KHR_debug GL_EXT_YUV_target GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control GL_EXT_texture_norm16 GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_OES_surfaceless_context GL_OVR_multiview GL_OVR_multiview2 GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_R8 GL_KHR_no_error GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OVR_multiview_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_EXT_buffer_storage GL_EXT
    _external_buffer GL_EXT_blit_framebuffer_params GL_EXT_clip_cull_distance GL_EXT_protected_textures GL_EXT_shader_non_constant_global_initializers GL_QCOM_texture_foveated GL_QCOM_shader_framebuffer_fetch_noncoherent GL_EXT_memory_object GL_EXT_memory_object_fd GL_EXT_EGL_image_array GL_NV_shader_noperspective_interpolation GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior GL_EXT_EGL_image_storage GL_EXT_blend_func_extended GL_EXT_clip_control
W/AudioTrack: Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control
    See the documentation of AudioTrack() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case
W/Unity: OnLevelWasLoaded was found on Reporter
    This message has been deprecated and will be removed in a later version of Unity.
    Add a delegate to SceneManager.sceneLoaded instead to get notifications after scene loading has completed

    (Filename:  Line: 356)
V/MediaRouter: Adding route: RouteInfo{ name=Телефон, description=null, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=Система types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO , presentationDisplay=null }
V/MediaRouter: Selecting route: RouteInfo{ name=Телефон, description=null, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=Система types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO , presentationDisplay=null }
I/Unity: UnityIAP Version: 1.20.0
    UnityEngine.Logger:Log(Object)
    UnityEngine.Purchasing.StandardPurchasingModule:Instance(AppStore)
    Assets.Core.Manager.PaymentsManager:GAEFJJGLMMO()

    (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 45)
I/UnityIAP: IAB helper created.
W/Unity: DontDestroyOnLoad only work for root GameObjects or components on root GameObjects.
    AppMetrica:Awake()

    [ line 540] 
    (Filename:  Line: 540)
I/AppMetrica: Initializing of Metrica, Release type, Version 3.2.2, API Level 70, Dated 09.08.2018.
I/UnityIAP: Starting in-app billing setup.
I/UnityIAP: Billing service connected.
I/UnityIAP: invoking callback
    Checking for in-app billing 3 support.
I/UnityIAP: In-app billing version 3 supported for zombie.survival.craft.z
I/UnityIAP: Subscriptions AVAILABLE.
I/UnityIAP: Subscription upgrade and downgrade are AVAILABLE.
I/UnityIAP: Subscriptions information parse AVAILABLE.
I/UnityIAP: VR supported.
I/UnityIAP: onIabSetupFinished: 0
I/UnityIAP: Requesting 471 products
I/UnityIAP: QueryInventory: 471
    invoking callback
I/UnityIAP: Querying owned items, item type: inapp
    Package name: zombie.survival.craft.z
    Calling getPurchases with continuation token: null
I/UnityIAP: Owned items response: 0
I/UnityIAP: Continuation token: null
    Querying SKU details.
Connected to process 6385 on device xiaomi-mi_a2_lite-24c2e93c0005
```

and

```
    2019-04-23 11:46:53.814 6265-6265/? I/urvival.craft.: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2019-04-23 11:46:54.193 6265-6265/zombie.survival.craft.z I/urvival.craft.: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2019-04-23 11:46:54.756 6265-6265/zombie.survival.craft.z I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
2019-04-23 11:46:54.771 6265-6265/zombie.survival.craft.z I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
2019-04-23 11:46:54.772 6265-6265/zombie.survival.craft.z I/MultiDex: Installing application
2019-04-23 11:46:54.772 6265-6265/zombie.survival.craft.z I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
2019-04-23 11:46:54.784 6265-6265/zombie.survival.craft.z D/FirebaseApp: Default FirebaseApp failed to initialize because no default options were found. This usually means that com.google.gms:google-services was not applied to your gradle project.
2019-04-23 11:46:54.784 6265-6265/zombie.survival.craft.z I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
2019-04-23 11:46:55.094 6265-6265/zombie.survival.craft.z D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2019-04-23 11:46:55.194 6265-6304/zombie.survival.craft.z I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 2df12b3, I07da2d9908
    Build Date                       : 10/04/18
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.25.03.01
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Reconstruct Branch               : 
2019-04-23 11:46:55.195 6265-6304/zombie.survival.craft.z I/Adreno: Build Config                     : S L 6.0.7 AArch32
2019-04-23 11:46:55.201 6265-6289/zombie.survival.craft.z D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2019-04-23 11:46:55.203 6265-6289/zombie.survival.craft.z I/DpmTcmClient: RegisterTcmMonitor from: com.android.okhttp.TcmIdleTimerMonitor
2019-04-23 11:46:55.241 6265-6304/zombie.survival.craft.z I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff110, ME: 0x005ff066
2019-04-23 11:46:55.288 6265-6304/zombie.survival.craft.z I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-04-23 11:46:55.288 6265-6304/zombie.survival.craft.z I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-04-23 11:46:55.290 6265-6304/zombie.survival.craft.z I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-04-23 11:46:55.290 6265-6304/zombie.survival.craft.z D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
2019-04-23 11:46:55.598 6265-6300/zombie.survival.craft.z W/urvival.craft.: Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;-><init>(Ljava/lang/Class;I)V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-04-23 11:46:55.678 6265-6300/zombie.survival.craft.z I/Unity: SystemInfo CPU = ARMv7 VFPv3 NEON, Cores = 8, Memory = 2826mb
2019-04-23 11:46:55.678 6265-6300/zombie.survival.craft.z I/Unity: SystemInfo ARM big.LITTLE configuration: 8 big (mask: 0xff), 0 little (mask: 0x0)
2019-04-23 11:46:55.679 6265-6300/zombie.survival.craft.z I/Unity: ApplicationInfo zombie.survival.craft.z version 1.11.11 build 321aec15-e27b-4ce5-ba0f-5a1541345263
2019-04-23 11:46:55.679 6265-6300/zombie.survival.craft.z I/Unity: Built from '2018.3/staging' branch, Version '2018.3.8f1 (fc0fe30d6d91)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'armeabi-v7a'
2019-04-23 11:46:55.727 6265-6293/zombie.survival.craft.z W/AnalyticsUserIDStore: initStore should have been called before calling setUserID
2019-04-23 11:46:55.730 6265-6293/zombie.survival.craft.z W/UserDataStore: initStore should have been called before calling setUserID
2019-04-23 11:46:56.800 6265-6300/zombie.survival.craft.z D/Unity:  GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_framebuffer_object GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_hdr GL_OES_texture_compression_astc GL_OES_texture_npot GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_OES_texture_3D GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_QCOM_alpha_test GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_EXT_sRGB GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_texture_format_sRGB_override GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_EXT_copy_image GL_EXT_geometry_shader GL_EXT_tessellation_shader GL_OES_texture_stencil8 GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks GL_OES_shader_image_atomic GL_OES_sample_variables GL_EXT_texture_border_clamp GL_EXT_EGL_i
2019-04-23 11:46:56.800 6265-6300/zombie.survival.craft.z D/Unity: mage_external_wrap_modes GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture2 GL_OES_shader_multisample_interpolation GL_EXT_texture_cube_map_array GL_EXT_draw_buffers_indexed GL_EXT_gpu_shader5 GL_EXT_robustness GL_EXT_texture_buffer GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch GL_ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch_depth_stencil GL_OES_texture_storage_multisample_2d_array GL_OES_sample_shading GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_EXT_debug_label GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering GL_ANDROID_extension_pack_es31a GL_EXT_primitive_bounding_box GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query GL_KHR_debug GL_EXT_YUV_target GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control GL_EXT_texture_norm16 GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_OES_surfaceless_context GL_OVR_multiview GL_OVR_multiview2 GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_R8 GL_KHR_no_error GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OVR_multiview_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_EXT_buffer_storage GL_EXT
2019-04-23 11:46:56.800 6265-6300/zombie.survival.craft.z D/Unity: _external_buffer GL_EXT_blit_framebuffer_params GL_EXT_clip_cull_distance GL_EXT_protected_textures GL_EXT_shader_non_constant_global_initializers GL_QCOM_texture_foveated GL_QCOM_shader_framebuffer_fetch_noncoherent GL_EXT_memory_object GL_EXT_memory_object_fd GL_EXT_EGL_image_array GL_NV_shader_noperspective_interpolation GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior GL_EXT_EGL_image_storage GL_EXT_blend_func_extended GL_EXT_clip_control
2019-04-23 11:46:56.887 6265-6357/zombie.survival.craft.z W/AudioTrack: Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control
2019-04-23 11:46:56.887 6265-6357/zombie.survival.craft.z W/AudioTrack: See the documentation of AudioTrack() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case
2019-04-23 11:46:58.771 6265-6300/zombie.survival.craft.z W/Unity: OnLevelWasLoaded was found on Reporter
    This message has been deprecated and will be removed in a later version of Unity.
    Add a delegate to SceneManager.sceneLoaded instead to get notifications after scene loading has completed

    (Filename:  Line: 356)
2019-04-23 11:47:01.053 6265-6300/zombie.survival.craft.z V/MediaRouter: Adding route: RouteInfo{ name=Телефон, description=null, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=Система types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO , presentationDisplay=null }
2019-04-23 11:47:01.065 6265-6300/zombie.survival.craft.z V/MediaRouter: Selecting route: RouteInfo{ name=Телефон, description=null, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=Система types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO , presentationDisplay=null }
2019-04-23 11:47:03.634 6265-6300/zombie.survival.craft.z I/Unity: UnityIAP Version: 1.20.0
    UnityEngine.Logger:Log(Object)
    UnityEngine.Purchasing.StandardPurchasingModule:Instance(AppStore)
    Assets.Core.Manager.PaymentsManager:GAEFJJGLMMO()

    (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 45)
2019-04-23 11:47:03.671 6265-6300/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: IAB helper created.
2019-04-23 11:47:03.831 6265-6300/zombie.survival.craft.z W/Unity: DontDestroyOnLoad only work for root GameObjects or components on root GameObjects.
    AppMetrica:Awake()

    [ line 540] 
    (Filename:  Line: 540)
2019-04-23 11:47:03.869 6265-6376/zombie.survival.craft.z I/AppMetrica: Initializing of Metrica, Release type, Version 3.2.2, API Level 70, Dated 09.08.2018.
2019-04-23 11:47:04.936 6265-6300/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: Starting in-app billing setup.
2019-04-23 11:47:04.970 6265-6265/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: Billing service connected.
2019-04-23 11:47:04.972 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: invoking callback
2019-04-23 11:47:04.972 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: Checking for in-app billing 3 support.
2019-04-23 11:47:04.976 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: In-app billing version 3 supported for zombie.survival.craft.z
2019-04-23 11:47:04.978 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: Subscriptions AVAILABLE.
2019-04-23 11:47:04.981 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: Subscription upgrade and downgrade are AVAILABLE.
2019-04-23 11:47:04.984 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: Subscriptions information parse AVAILABLE.
2019-04-23 11:47:04.987 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: VR supported.
2019-04-23 11:47:04.988 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: onIabSetupFinished: 0
2019-04-23 11:47:04.989 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: Requesting 471 products
2019-04-23 11:47:04.990 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: QueryInventory: 471
2019-04-23 11:47:04.990 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: invoking callback
2019-04-23 11:47:04.991 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: Querying owned items, item type: inapp
2019-04-23 11:47:04.991 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: Package name: zombie.survival.craft.z
2019-04-23 11:47:04.991 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: Calling getPurchases with continuation token: null
2019-04-23 11:47:04.996 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: Owned items response: 0
2019-04-23 11:47:04.997 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: Continuation token: null
2019-04-23 11:47:04.997 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: Querying SKU details.
2019-04-23 11:47:05.152 6265-6357/zombie.survival.craft.z D/AudioTrack: stop() called with 200704 frames delivered
2019-04-23 11:47:05.305 6265-6265/zombie.survival.craft.z W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@152307
2019-04-23 11:47:05.561 6265-6265/zombie.survival.craft.z D/LVLDL: Service Bound
2019-04-23 11:47:05.582 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: Querying owned items, item type: subs
2019-04-23 11:47:05.582 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: Package name: zombie.survival.craft.z
2019-04-23 11:47:05.582 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: Calling getPurchases with continuation token: null
2019-04-23 11:47:05.585 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: Owned items response: 0
2019-04-23 11:47:05.586 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: Continuation token: null
2019-04-23 11:47:05.586 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: Querying SKU details.
2019-04-23 11:47:05.785 6265-6265/zombie.survival.craft.z I/LicenseChecker: Binding to licensing service.
2019-04-23 11:47:05.895 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: Querying owned items' purchase history, item type: subs
2019-04-23 11:47:05.895 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: Package name: zombie.survival.craft.z
2019-04-23 11:47:05.895 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: Calling getPurchaseHistory with continuation token: null
2019-04-23 11:47:05.904 6265-6265/zombie.survival.craft.z I/LicenseChecker: Calling checkLicense on service for zombie.survival.craft.z
2019-04-23 11:47:05.906 6265-6265/zombie.survival.craft.z I/LicenseChecker: Start monitoring timeout.
2019-04-23 11:47:06.336 6265-6454/zombie.survival.craft.z I/LicenseChecker: Received response.
2019-04-23 11:47:06.336 6265-6454/zombie.survival.craft.z I/LicenseChecker: Clearing timeout.
2019-04-23 11:47:06.766 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: Purchase history response: 0
2019-04-23 11:47:06.766 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: Continuation token: null
2019-04-23 11:47:06.767 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: onQueryInventoryFinished: true
2019-04-23 11:47:06.767 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: Inventory refresh successful. (response: 0:OK)
2019-04-23 11:47:06.777 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: The number of owned skus is0
2019-04-23 11:47:06.778 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: The number of purchased skus is0
2019-04-23 11:47:06.778 6265-6407/zombie.survival.craft.z I/UnityIAP: The number of subscriptions purchased history is0
2019-04-23 11:48:05.767 6265-6274/zombie.survival.craft.z W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
2019-04-23 11:49:05.624 6265-6265/zombie.survival.craft.z D/CustomIntentService: onDestroy
```

I can not imagine what could happen in a couple of days.

**UPDATE**: work on samsung galaxy A7 (2018) (android 8). But steel dont work other devices

Comment: I was helped by the answer from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059370/google-android-lvl-checklicense-service-timeout
But still had to change Google account